# Set billing cycle date on Stripe checkout session create (or update subscription with a new billing_cycle_anchor)

Tags: stripe-payments, subscription

I'm creating a SaaS with 4 subscription plans: 1 free and 3 paid.

Users can stay in the Free Plan always as they want, but when a user change to a paid subscription, I want to set same billing date as previous Free Plan and only pay (at billing cycle end) from current date to previous free plan end date. I'm using the checkout session create API endpoint, I don't want to use the subscription create API endpoint because I need to control a lot of more things.

For example:

1. User singup at **15-02** with the Free Plan, then the next Free Plan renew is at **15-03**.
2. At **20-02** user update subscription to a Paid one, then I redirect to checkout Stripe screen using the checkout Session Create API URL. **Problem**: The Checkout Session Create endpoint does not allow to set the `billing_cycle_anchor` timestamp. Then the subscription billing cycle will be **20-02** / **20-03**.
3. I receive the subscription create notification at backend webhook.
4. I want to update the subscription to set the correct billing cycle (**15-02** / **15-03**), then the user will pay on **15-03** the difference from **20-02** and **15-03** and at **15-03** the subscription will be renewed to **15-04**.

There are any way to do it without trials or subscription schedules?

Thanks!

**UPDATE 1:** Maybe I can cancel the subscription on webhook and create a new subscription with the correct `billing_cycle_anchor`? It's a "right-way" solution?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to do a [proration update](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/prorations). It should be done via the regular Subscription API, in other words, you can't do it with just the Checkout API, and also shouldn't cancel and recreate the Subscription as you mentioned.

When it's not necessary for Subscription Schedule, it's still more "right" to use the regular Subscription Update API. Stripe has a comprehensive guide on [their Doc](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/prorations) and [their API Reference](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update) that worth checking out.

> By default, we prorate subscription changes. For example, if a
> customer signs up on May 1 for a ¥100 price, she'll be billed ¥100
> immediately. If on May 15 she switches to a ¥200 price, then on June 1
> she'll be billed ¥250 (¥200 for a renewal of her subscription, plus a
> ¥50 prorating adjustment for half of the previous month's ¥100
> difference). Similarly, a downgrade will generate a credit to be
> applied to the next invoice. We also prorate when you make quantity
> changes.

Comment: Finally, the cancel & create is a good solution. Stripe support response: "It's great that you've found another way to achieve the outcome, very creative!".

The problem is not a subscription change, the problem is set the billing cycle on a new subscription from checkout, that is not available (yet).

Answer (score 1):

`billing_cycle_anchor` can be set via the Checkout session since since 26 April, 2023. [See docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-subscription_data-billing_cycle_anchor).

Example in JSON pseudo-code:

```json
{
    "mode": "subscription",
    "subscription_data": {
        "billing_cycle_anchor": 1682985600
    }
}
```